# How do i move three.js model to right side of screen?

Tags: javascript, html, css, three.js

I have just started learning `three.js` and I want to know if it is possible to move a 3d model to the right side of the screen instead of being centered in the middle.

Here is an image to help with the explanation of what I am trying to do.

[image: source]

([link to the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rbR5k.jpg))

The `three.js` code looks like this:

```
  <script>
  let scene, carMesh, camera, renderer;

  init();
  animate();

  function init() {
    scene = new THREE.Scene();
    scene.background = new THREE.Color(0xFFFFFF);

    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias:true});
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(25,window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight,1,5000);
    camera.position.set(1500, 1200, 2000);


    controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
    controls.addEventListener('change', renderer);

    hlight = new THREE.AmbientLight (0x404040,100);
    scene.add(hlight);

    directionalLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff,100);
    directionalLight.position.set(0,1,0);
    directionalLight.castShadow = true;
    scene.add(directionalLight);

    light = new THREE.PointLight(0xc4c4c4,10);
    light.position.set(0,300,500);
    scene.add(light);

    light2 = new THREE.PointLight(0xc4c4c4,10);
    light2.position.set(500,100,0);
    scene.add(light2);

    light3 = new THREE.PointLight(0xc4c4c4,10);
    light3.position.set(0,100,-500);
    scene.add(light3);

    light4 = new THREE.PointLight(0xc4c4c4,10);
    light4.position.set(-500,300,500);
    scene.add(light4);

    let loader = new THREE.GLTFLoader();
    loader.load('scene.gltf', function(gltf){
      scene.add(gltf.scene);
      carMesh = gltf.scene.children[0];
      carMesh.scale.set(0.5,0.5,0.5);
      camera.lookAt(carMesh.position);

    });
  }

  function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    renderer.render(scene,camera);
    controls.update(scene,);
  }

  window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize, false );

  function onWindowResize(){

  camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
  camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

  renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

}

</script>
```

Many thanks
Ollie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has little to to with Three.js. Rather, it is a question of the page's layout, and the relative placement of the Three.js dom element in the dom tree.

In your code, the Three.js content is a child of the `body` element:

```
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
```

If you want to position it in a certain way, e.g. on the right side, you can position an element, typically a `div`, and use this as the parent element of the Three.js content.

A very simple solution is:

```
<div id="container" style="float: right"></div>
...
document.getElementById("container").appendChild(renderer.domElement);
```

Of course, to meet your needs, you may have to style/position other elements on your page as well, e.g. the element left of the Three.js `div`. This can be achieved by css, which you can define either inline in the elements via `style`, or in a separate  section of your document (the preferred approach).